# php laravel - changes to php files in model not reflected in the output

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to php and laravel development. I am working on an existing php+laravel project. and I am trying to understand how it works. the existing application is working fine.. but when I make some changes to the php files in models, controller folder, the changes are not reflected in the output.

what command should I run to build everything?

thanks

Comment: you should make an example, post some codes, to make your problem clearly

Comment: For example: lets say I have employee.php in my app/models folder.. I will comment the whole code inside this file.. now I am expecting my application to throw an error or atleast shouldnt show the employee details.. but my code is still working fine as before showing employee details.. my question is what is that procedure to be done once you make some changes to your code?   What i did is - 1. made changes to the code. 2. restarted apache server.  I believe there is an intermediate step which I am missing.

Comment: It will work immediately if you comment your codes in the right place, you don't need to restart apache. So I think maybe you commented codes in wrong file.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced this a few times myself, and the reason was that my cached view had not been updated. Try emptying the following folders:

```
/app/storage/cache
/app/storage/views
```

No need to restart the web-server.

**Note!** Some of the `storage` folders may contain a git placeholder, such as a `.gitkeep` file, it get git to commit "empty" folders. Don't delete that file, if you need the folder to get committed.

---

**Update:** You can use the artisan command `view:clear` to clear the cached views, instead of emptying the folders yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem on my linux machine.

What I did was restart ngnix (`service ngnix restart`) and also restart php (`service php5-fpm restart`) and now the changes are showing again.

Comment: Hi #Cosmin Bacanu, this solution helped why is it that you needed to restart php to reflect the changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know why it worked. I just tried a lot of things and this is what ended up working.